# Degrees of Veronese varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, intersection-theory

Let $ \nu = \nu_{n,d} : \mathbb{P}^{n} \to \mathbb{P}^N $ be the Veronese map : $ [Z_0 , \dots , Z_n ] \to [ \ \dots , Z^I , \dots \ ] $ where : $ N = \begin{pmatrix} n+d \\ d \end{pmatrix} - 1 $, and $ Z^I $ ranges over monomials of degree $ d $ in $ n+1 $ variables. The image $ \Phi = \Phi_{n,d} \subset \mathbb{P}^n $ of the Veronese map $ \nu = \nu_{n,d} $ is called the $ d $ -th Veronese variety of $ \mathbb{P}^n $, as is any subvariety of $ \mathbb{P}^N $ projectively equivalent to it.

- **Theorem** : The degree of $ \Phi_{n,d} $ is $ d^n $
- **Proof** : The degree of $ \Phi $ is the cardinality of its intersection with $ n$ general hyperplanes $ H_1 , \dots ,H_n \subset \mathbb{P}^n $ ; since the map $ \nu $ is one-to-one, this is in turn the cardinality of the intersection $ \nu^{-1} (H_1 ) \cap \dots \cap \nu^{-1} (H_n ) \subset \mathbb{P}^n $. The preimages of the hyperplanes $ H_i $ are $ n $ general hypersurfaces of degree $d$ in $ \mathbb{P}^n $. By Bezout's theorem, the cardinality of their intersection is $d^n $.
- **Question** : In the proof above about how to find the degree of a Veronese variety $ \Phi_{n,d} $ which i found in a free text book on the net, i would like to ask you why is the degree of $ \Phi $ the cardinality of its intersection with $ n $ general hyperplanes $ H_1 , \dots ,H_n \subset \mathbb{P}^n $ ? Why do we introduce this machinery of $ n $ general hyperplanes $ H_1 , \dots ,H_n \subset \mathbb{P}^n $ in this story ? What does this machinery of $ n $ general hyperplanes $ H_1 , \dots ,H_n \subset \mathbb{P}^n $ represent when we talk about $ \Phi_{n,d} $ as a image of $ \mathbb{P}^n $ by the Veronese map $ \nu $ ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: This is simply one classical definition of degree of a closed subvariety in $\mathbb{P}^n$. Which definition of degree have you learned?

Comment: I only use the following definition : Let $ f : Y \to X $ be a proprer map of schemes. If $ A \subset Y $ a subvariety and $ \mathrm{dim} (A) = \mathrm{dim} (f(A)) $ then, $ f_{|A} : A \to f(A) $ is generically finite. in the sens that : $ K(A) $ is a finite extention of the field $ K(f(A)) $. ... To be continued ...

Comment: ... Geometrically, the condition can be expressed by saying that for a generic point $ x \in f(A) $, the preimage $ y := f_{|A} (x) $ in $ A $ is a finite scheme. In this case, the degree $ n= [K(A) : K(f(A)) ] $ is equal to the degree of $ y $ over $ x $ for a dense open subset of $ x \in f(A) $, and this common value $ n $ is called the degree of the covering of $ f(A) $ by $ A $.

Comment: Equivalence of the two definitions is sketched in Harris, Algebraic geometry. Look for proposition 7.16.