# Degree of a Subvariety of a Veronese Variety cut out by a curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, curves, projective-space, intersection-theory

The veronese map $\nu_{n,d}: \mathbb{P}^n\longrightarrow \mathbb{P}^{{{d+n}\choose{n}}-1}$ is defined by $[...,x_j,...]\longrightarrow [...,M_k,...]$, where $M_k$ are all the monomials of degree $d$ in $\{...,x_j,...\}$. In the stackexchange post, [Degrees of Veronese varieties](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2664626/degrees-of-veronese-varieties), it is pointed out that the degree of the the image $\nu_{n,d}(\mathbb{P}^n)$, here called a Veronese variety, is given by $d^n$.

**Question**: What is the degree of $\nu_{n,d}(C)$, for any curve $C\subset \mathbb{P}^n$ of degree $a$?

Following the rational of the linked post, is this degree simply $ad^n$?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. A hyperplane section of the Veronese variety is a hypersurface of degree $d^n$ in $\mathbb P^n$, so it intersects a curve of degree $a$ in $ad^n$ points.

Comment: But does the curve $\nu_{n,d}(C)$ have the same degree as $C$? Or are we intersecting in the domain?

Comment: Hmm, I could have sworn I replied to this comment the other day. Anyway, we are intersecting in the domain; I suppose on the level of sets this is something like $\#(\nu_{n,d}(C) \cap H) = \#(C \cap \nu_{n,d}^{-1}(H))$ for a sufficiently general hyperplane $H \subset \mathbb P^n$.

Comment: You are off by one in the power. A hyperplane section of the Veronese variety is a degree $d$ hypersurface in $\mathbb{P^n}$ and to get the degree of a curve in $\mathbb{P}^n$ you need to intersect with such hypersurfaces $n-1$, not $n$, times.